# How to handle multiple buttons with Input in Razor view Using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, view

I saw many post regarding multiple button calling Action method, But those are all without Input.

I have Razor View. It will generate multiple Inputs and Buttons

**Example**

**Item View**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Prod)
{
    <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" class="form-control txtQty">

    <button type="button" data-src="@(item.ItemID)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddValue", "MyController")'" id="btnAddItem-@(item.ItemID)" style="margin-top: 15px;">Add</button>
}
```

> So above code **may generate, 5 textboxes and 5 Add button**, every button click will call below action method.
>
> How can I get the respective textbox value. For instance, if user enter value = 16.5 on 5th textbox, and click 5th button, I need to get the value of what user entered on that 5th textbox

**ActionResult method**

```
public ActionResult AddValue()
{
    //I need to get the entered textbox value
    return RedirectToAction("Item");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to capture input for that specific line or row, then you could enclose them with a form tag during the loop.

EDIT: Don't forget to add a Name attribute to your input field. I used `Quantity` for input and `ID` for the button. Then change button to `type="submit"` and assign the id to its value by `value="@item.ItemID"`.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Prod)
{
    <form type="POST" action="@Url.Action('AddValue')">
       <input type="text" name="Quantity" id="txtQuantity" class="form-control txtQty">

       <button name="ID" value="@item.ItemID" type="submit" data-src="@(item.ItemID)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnAddItem-@(item.ItemID)" style="margin-top: 15px;">Add</button>
    </form>
}
```

Then in your controller, add `[HttpPost]` attribute and since you're not using any model, get the submitted value by accessing `Request[name]`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddValue()
{
    // input
    var value = Request["Quantity"];

    // button
    var value = Request["ID"];
    return RedirectToAction("Item");
}
```

Comment: How can I get the txtbox value in Controller?.

Comment: @Liamneesan sorry I forgot to answer that, I edited the answer with the complete one.